# Function reference undefined local object React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React Component with some local variables and methods. The methods declaration order does not matter ( ? ) since they are available from anywhere I want to call them from component once declared.

But when I try to reference a method in a local variable, it gives undefined if the method is declared below the local variable, why?
Example:

```
//THIS WORKS

someFunction = () => {
  //some logic
}

localVariable = [
  {name: 'test', myFunction: this.someFunction},
  {name: 'test2', myFunction: this.someFunction}
}

//console.log(localVariable) gives 'function' at 'myFunction' key

//THIS DOES NOT WORK

localVariable = [
  {name: 'test', myFunction: this.someFunction},
  {name: 'test2', myFunction: this.someFunction}
}

someFunction = () => {
  //some logic
}

//console.log(localVariable) give 'undefined' at 'myFunction' key

//but also if I pass do not pass only the reference it works

localVariable = [
  {name: 'test', myFunction: () => this.someFunction()},
  {name: 'test2', myFunction: () => this.someFunction()}
}

someFunction = () => {
  //some logic
}
```

Comment: Could you prove whole component's code?

Comment: The syntax that you're using is just a replacement for the `constructor` that is why the order matters. Try: `someFunction() {}` instead of `someFunction = () => {}`.

Comment: @MikhailKatrin, I can provide an example.

Comment: @Titus, now it is clear, but why the third example is working?

Comment: That is because you access `this.someFunction` when `myFunction` is called not when the object is created.

Comment: @Titus It is clear now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to below link,

http://javascript.info/function-expressions-arrows

As you are using arrow function syntax to create someFunction, in actual you are making a variable which is equal to the function you assigned to it.

So when you defined your local variable it does not get the reference as it was not defined.

It is the matter of function declaration and function as expression.

A Function Expression is created when the execution reaches it and is usable from then on.

Comment: Also, checkout **Function Expression vs Function Declaration** on the above link.

Comment: So if I convert it from Function Expression to Function Declaration it will be available  before declaration because of Hoisting. https://gomakethings.com/function-expressions-vs-function-declarations/

But why is the third example working? When I do not pass a reference, but another function?

Comment: 1. You are creating an object as **localVariable** and property as a method named **myFunction**.  2. In the first case, you are assigning a function which is created, thus works well.  3. In the second case, you are assigning a function which is not yet defined. Thus it fails.  4. In third case, you are assigning an arrow function which does not have it's own 'this' and refers to parent functional scope. At the time of defining localVariable, 'this.someFunction' was not defined on **this** but after assigning a **localVariable** you assign a new function to 'this.someFunction'. Thus it works.

Comment: I really do not understand this part: 'At the time of defining localVariable, 'this.someFunction' was not defined on this but after assigning a localVariable you assign a new function to 'this.someFunction'. 
Do you mean that when 'localVariable' is created 'someFunction' does not exist, but I assign to it an arrow function, which when is called 'someFunction' exists, so it works? Thank you.

Comment: In the third case, you are assigning a new function as an arrow function to myFunction property, which will execute when you will call it, not when you define it. When you defined a myFunction property that time someFunction was undefined and after that, you defined it below localVariable. If you call localVariable[0].myFunction() before defining someFunction **(THIRD CASE)** it will show an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set `localVariable` inside the component's class constructor.

```
class YourClassName extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.localVariable = [
      {name: 'test', myFunction: this.someFunction},
      {name: 'test2', myFunction: this.someFunction}
    ]
  }
  someFunction = () => {
    // logic...
  }
}
```

Comment: I would like to avoid using a constructor